# Confused about passing by reference in this Python function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this simple Python 2.7 function:

```
def sort_rows(mat): 
    mat = [sorted(i) for i in mat]
```

However, when I run:

```
M = [[4, 5, 2, 8], [3, 9, 6, 7]]
sort_rows(M)
print(M)
```

I get

```
[[4, 5, 2, 8], [3, 9, 6, 7]]
```

Why wasn't `M` edited? I thought python functions passed lists by reference? Am I missing something?

Comment: Python is pass by value. Thus, return the new list and reassign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your `sort_rows` is called `mat` points to the same list that `M` points to.  This statement, however, changes that:

```
mat = [sorted(i) for i in mat]
```

After the above is executed, `mat` now points to a different list.  `M` is unchanged.

To change `M` in place:

```
>>> def sort_rows(mat): 
...     for i, row in enumerate(mat):
...         mat[i] = sorted(row)
... 
>>> sort_rows(M)
>>> M
[[2, 4, 5, 8], [3, 6, 7, 9]]
```

The statement `mat[i] = sorted(row)` changes the i-th element of `mat` but does not change the list that `mat` points to.  Hence, `M` is changed also.

Alternatively, you can have your function return a list with sorted rows:

```
>>> def rowsort(mat):
...     return [sorted(i) for i in mat]
... 
>>> M = [[4, 5, 2, 8], [3, 9, 6, 7]]
>>> M = rowsort(M)
>>> M
[[2, 4, 5, 8], [3, 6, 7, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the `sorted` function doesn't sort the list in place, if you want it be sorted in place, you can use `list.sort()` method:

```
def sort_rows(mat): 
    [i.sort() for i in mat]

M = [[4, 5, 2, 8], [3, 9, 6, 7]]
sort_rows(M)
print(M)

# [[2, 4, 5, 8], [3, 6, 7, 9]]
```

`sorted` returns a new list but the original list doesn't change:

```
x = [3, 2, 1, 4]

sorted(x)
# [1, 2, 3, 4]

x
# [3, 2, 1, 4]                  # x doesn't change here
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the return function to return the variable mat at the end of sort row.

```
return M
```

Then if you try-

```
print(sort_rows(M))
```

you should get the result you want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the return function to return the variable mat at the end of sort row.

return M

Then if you try

print(sort_rows(M))

you should get the result you want.

I mean return mat I apologize